# autocomplete - show the whole list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, click, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code :

```
var myList = [ "Avellino", "Enna", "Frosinone" ];

myInput.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {            
        var data = $.grep(myList, function(value) {
            return value.substring(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase();
        });            

        response(data);
    },        
    appendTo: "#myDiv"
});
```

and I'd like, when I click on the input box, show the list of all elements (with the same autocomplete box for choose value) of `myList`.

I suppose I need a third part handler, like :

```
myInput.focus(function () {

});
```

but I don't know how to dialogate with the autocomplete. Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[@jasonlfunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396111/497356) is halfway there-- You have to call `search` on the autocomplete widget upon `focus` to get this to work:

```
var myList = [ "Avellino", "Enna", "Frosinone" ];

$('#myInput').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {            
        var data = $.grep(myList, function(value) {
            return value.substring(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase();
        });            

        response(data);
    }
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BRDBd/

Comment: Actually, my solution is better because it handles the case where you type something, click away, and then focus the element again... But it's not a contest.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [minLength](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength) option for the autocomplete plugin. Setting it to zero should do what you want.

```
var myList = [ "Avellino", "Enna", "Frosinone" ];

myInput.autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {            
        var data = $.grep(myList, function(value) {
            return value.substring(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase();
        });            

        response(data);
    },        
    appendTo: "#myDiv"
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("search",$(this).val());
});​;
```

Comment: Uhm, no it doesnt work! http://jsfiddle.net/Ek8nS/  if I click on the input I can't see the list..

Comment: perfect answer, Thanks dude :)